# C# syntax error -

Tags: c#

I'm not quite sure why I'm getting an error in the 1 + annIntRate and numYears variables in my calcButton event handler.  The error I'm getting for both variables is "Cannot convert from decimal double", but both should be decimals.  Please help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Present_Value
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //  Using the InputIsValid method to convert the users input and stores
        // it in the arguments (passed by reference).  If the conversion
        // is successful, the method returns true.  Otherwise it returns false.
        private bool InputIsValid(ref decimal futureValue, ref decimal annIntRate, ref decimal numYears)
        {
            // Flag variable to indicate whether the input is good 
            bool inputGood = false;

            // Try to convert all inputs to decimal.
            if (decimal.TryParse(futureAmtTextBox.Text, out futureValue))
            {
                if (decimal.TryParse(yearsTextBox.Text, out numYears))
                {
                    if (decimal.TryParse(rateTextBox.Text, out annIntRate))
                    {
                        //All inputs are good.
                        inputGood = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Display an error message for anIntRate
                        MessageBox.Show("Annual Interest Rate is invalid.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Display  an error message for the numYears
                    MessageBox.Show("Years in Savings is invalid.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Dislay an error message for future value
                MessageBox.Show("Future amount is invalid");
            }
            // Return the reulst.
            return inputGood;
        }



        private void calcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Variables for for the present, future value,
            // annual interest rate, and number of years
            decimal futureValue = 0m, annIntRate = 0m,  numYears = 0m;

            if (InputIsValid(ref futureValue, ref annIntRate, ref numYears))
            {
                // Calculate Present Value
               decimal presentValue = (decimal)futureValue / (decimal)Math.Pow((**1 + annIntRate**), **numYears**);

                presentValLabel.Text = presentValue.ToString("C");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Math.Pow` expects `double` argument, not `decimal`.

Comment: Additionally, What you are specifically doing with decimal here? why not a `double` instead?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I changed this line to this and it worked:    // Calculate Present Value
               decimal presentValue = (decimal)futureValue / (decimal)Math.Pow((double)(1 + annIntRate), (double)numYears);

Comment: Thanks AlexD and un-lucky...you were spot on.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
decimal presentValue = (decimal) futureValue / (decimal) Math.Pow((double) (1 + annIntRate), (double) numYears);
```

Because [Math.Pow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) Takes (Double, Double) which in returns, returns a specified number raised to the specified power.